# lib/SplashKit.cs(15240,3): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#

Coding is completely new to mem, I'm trying to complete my first ever code. Which I understand is meant to be easy. However, I keep getting the following mistakes.

1. lib/SplashKit.cs(15240,3): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
2. lib/SplashKit.cs(19453,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

This is the code.

```
using System;
using SplashKitSDK;


0 references 
public class Program
{
0 references 
public static void Main()
{
Console.WriteLine("HelloWorld");

}
}
```